Caused by net.sqlcipher.InvalidRowColumnException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
Observed crash in firebase crashlytics with the below exceptions:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start receiver com.welldoc.platform.android.reminder.ReminderReceiver: net.sqlcipher.InvalidRowColumnException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
&
Caused by net.sqlcipher.InvalidRowColumnException
get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
This crash we are observing when app is in background. I already read that if we use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead of getColumnIndex(String) will give us the proper error message but do we have any other solution other than this? Below is the code of how I am getting data from the DB. Can you please see the code and please help me if I am doing something wrong.
public MedEntryDTO GetLatestBolusInsulinEntryQueryDTO() {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MedEntry WHERE InsulinType = 's' OR InsulinType = 'S' ORDER BY UnixTimeStampInMillis DESC LIMIT 1", null);
        MedEntryDTO dto = null;
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                dto = GetRecord(cursor);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return dto;
    }

private MedEntryDTO GetRecord(Cursor cursor) {
        MedEntryDTO dto = new MedEntryDTO();
        dto.ActivityTypeId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ActivityTypeId"));
        dto.CreatedBy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CreatedBy"));
        dto.EntrySourceId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("EntrySourceId"));
        dto.PatientId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("PatientId"));
        dto.MedAdminstrationId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MedAdminstrationId"));
        dto.MedicationId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("MedicationId"));
        return dto;
    }

